# How to show time picker dialog with manual (keyboard) entry by default?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

Time picker dialog shows circular timings by default to select date and time. Instead of it Need to show keyboard entry by default to select date and time. While showing time picker dialog in circular style, it has keyboard icon to change circular style to manual entry style. This feature is available from Android Oreo OS devices. How to show Time picker dialog with manual(keyboard) entry by default in supporting devices ?

[image: Time picker dialog with manual(keyboard) entry]

Comment: You got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

The time picker can be started in text input mode with:

```
MaterialTimePicker.Builder().setInputMode(INPUT_MODE_KEYBOARD)
```

For example:

```
val picker =
    MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
        .setTitleText(R.string.Set_time)
        .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
        .setHour(12)
        .setMinute(30)
        .setInputMode(MaterialTimePicker.INPUT_MODE_KEYBOARD)
        .build()

picker.show(supportFragmentManager, "TimePicker")
```

Source: https://material.io/components/time-pickers/android#using-time-pickers

Answer (score 0):

In your `showTimePicker()` function you can set the `initialEntryMode`.
By default it's `TimePickerEntryMode.dial` but you can change it to `TimePickerEntryMode.input`.

Just add: `initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,`

Comment: @Maksikm Can you please explain. Or sample code may be helpful