# Changing Android Time Picker Initial Display Style

Tags: android, timepickerdialog

I'm trying to set the TimePickerDialog's initial display from the clock to the number scroll, but I can't seem to find anything that could set the initial display as to what I want. For reference:

Current Initial TimePickerDialog Display
[image: Initial TimePickerDialog Display]

Expected Initial TimePickerDialog Display
[image: Expected TimePickerDialog Display]

Is that possible? I'd like to avoid clicking the toggle/switch to different style button if possible.

I tried checking on the properties and methods of the timepickerdialog but I can't seem to find anything that relates to its initial display.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/69369206/860227